# android...coordinatorlayout Error

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I installed Android Studio and wanted to make new project but im getting android...coordinatorlayout error on Design page.

My IDE Status:
Using latest build tools,
IDE is up to date,
Using android 4.0 for project and 4.0 is installed.

My styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

[Here is picture about that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXkoL.png)

Comment: hi, prodrias agregar el codigo xml.

Comment: @JuanEstebanLondoñoTabares Hello, I translated your comment, but which xml file to add?

Comment: the XML where it shows you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that mistake can be because you haven't included Constraintlayout's dependency on the grade.

**Add ConstraintLayout to your project**

To use ConstraintLayout in your project, proceed as follows:

Ensure you have the maven.google.com repository declared in your module-level build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```

Add the library as a dependency in the same build.gradle file, as shown in the example below. Note that the latest version might be different than what is shown in the example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
}
```

In the toolbar or sync notification, click Sync Project with Gradle Files.
Now you're ready to build your layout with ConstraintLayout.

You can find more documentation in the following link.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

use gradle 4.9

configure on demand, off

gradle plugin 3.1.4

File Invalidate Cache/restart

sync project with gradle

build

Comment: Hello, I cant update my gradle, changing gradle path and changing version but IDE is still installing 4.4 on syncing

Comment: search for file gradle-wraper.properties and edit this line
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip

Comment: Thank you so much! Phantom Lord